# How can I get the Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro volume control to work?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I've been using the X-Fi for some time on Windows and it works great. However, on my MacBook Pro I can't get the volume control to work.

I see the device in "System Preferences -> Sound" and in "Audio MIDI Setup" and I can switch output to it and it works great, except for volume control. Is it possible to get it to work too?

Comment: Vlad - I merged all the 4 tags you created into audio since we probably don't need a ton of new tags for people to find audio related questions to filter out or search to answer. Hit me up in the [better tagging room on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2510/better-tags-for-ask-different) if you have questions on when to make a new tag rather than using the ones we have.

Comment: So it's digital output right?

Comment: Yes, the Mac sees the soundcard as digital output. I'm using it to listen to music on my headset so it's pretty annoying that the volume control/knob is not working

Comment: Are you asking about volume controls on the X-Fi hardware, or the volume controls on the Mac/Mac OS?

Comment: @iynque neither work. I would be happy if I could get any of them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I found so far is to use [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower) as an intermediate filter between PC output and the X-Fi. This allows to control volume from Mac OSX at the price of some sound processing. I cannot comment yet on sound quality but on first auditions it seems to sound better than setting the volume to 1/100 in Songbird (my FLAC player).